# Adding columns with easting and northing of points using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, distance, coordinates

I've got LSOA dataset with centroids weighted by population. What I am trying to do is get coordinates of those points (centroids) so that I can then calculate distances to centroids outside of ArcMap (not the full licence).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Centroids are geocoded and do appear on a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Add XY Coordinates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm) tool which will create two fields and populate them with the coordinates of the points and is available under the basic license. The units of the XY coordinates will be determined by the coordinate system of the input layer.